# SQL include entries with no data

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Here is my sql statement in Oracle that I am working with:

```
SELECT FACILITY.fac_name
, SUM(FEE_LOG.fee_amount) AS TOTAL_FEES 
FROM FACILITY
, BOOK_DETAIL
, TRANS_LOG
, FEE_LOG
, TRANS_TYPE 
WHERE
FACILITY.fac_id = BOOK_DETAIL.fac_id 
AND BOOK_DETAIL.bkdt_id = TRANS_LOG.bkdt_id 
AND TRANS_LOG.trans_id = FEE_LOG.trans_id 
AND TRANS_LOG.trans_type_id = TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_id 
AND 
(
    TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_desc = 'LOST' 
    OR TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_desc = 'CHECKIN'
)
GROUP BY FACILITY.fac_name;
```

It outputs something similar to this:

```
FACILITY          TOTAL_FEES
Facility 1        8.45
Facility 2        4.23
Facility 3        5.23
```

I have 2 other facilities but they do not have any fees associated with them. I want to show them as 0

So the output would be like:

```
FACILITY          TOTAL_FEES
Facility 1        8.45
Facility 2        4.23
Facility 3        5.23
Facility 4        0
Facility 5        0
```

ER Diagram

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: You need to use a `left join` instead of a where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of implicit `INNER JOIN` for the `FEE_LOG` table

```
SELECT FACILITY.fac_name
     , SUM(FEE_LOG.fee_amount) AS TOTAL_FEES 
FROM FACILITY
JOIN BOOK_DETAIL ON FACILITY.fac_id = BOOK_DETAIL.fac_id 
JOIN TRANS_LOG ON BOOK_DETAIL.bkdt_id = TRANS_LOG.bkdt_id 
LEFT JOIN FEE_LOG ON TRANS_LOG.trans_id = FEE_LOG.trans_id 
JOIN TRANS_TYPE  TRANS_LOG.trans_type_id = TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_id 
WHERE TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_desc IN ('LOST', 'CHECKIN')
GROUP BY FACILITY.fac_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use outer joins and the on clause:

```
SELECT FACILITY.fac_name, SUM(nvl(FEE_LOG.fee_amount,0)) AS TOTAL_FEES
  FROM FACILITY
  left join BOOK_DETAIL
    on FACILITY.fac_id = BOOK_DETAIL.fac_id
  left join TRANS_LOG
    on BOOK_DETAIL.bkdt_id = TRANS_LOG.bkdt_id
  left join FEE_LOG
    on TRANS_LOG.trans_id = FEE_LOG.trans_id
  left join TRANS_TYPE
    on TRANS_LOG.trans_type_id = TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_id
   and TRANS_TYPE.trans_type_desc in ('LOST', 'CHECKIN')
 GROUP BY FACILITY.fac_name;
```

Note: If these facilities you are referring to, that do not have any fees, have rows on BOOK_DETAIL or TRANS_LOG you can replace the outer join with an inner join (for just those tables). Any table at which point there may or may not be a related record you have to use an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.fac_name
, coalesce(SUM(fl.fee_amount),0) AS TOTAL_FEES 
FROM FACILITY AS f
INNER JOIN BOOK_DETAIL AS bd 
    ON bd.fac_id = f.fac_id
INNER JOIN TRANS_LOG AS tl
    ON tl.bkdt_id = bd.bkdt_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN FEE_LOG AS fl
    ON fl.trans_id = tl.trans_id
INNER JOIN TRANS_TYPE AS tt
    ON tt.trans_type_id = tl.trans_type_id 
WHERE tt.trans_type_desc in ('LOST' , 'CHECKIN')
GROUP BY f.fac_name;
```

NB: when you list tables after `from` with commas between them you're effectively using a `cross join`.

When you add a condition to your `where` statement matching a field from one table to a field from another, the join becomes an `inner join`.

To select all records from one table along with any matches which may or may not exist from another you need an `outer join`.

There are 3 types:

- `left outer join` where you want all records from the first table listed and any matching records from the second.
- `right outer join` for all records from the second with only matches from the first.
- `full outer join` is all records from both tables, alongside one another where there's a match.

You should always specify the type of join rather than implying it through `where` clauses / commas, as this makes your intentions clearer and thus your code more readable.